# Obtain the surfaces curves in a figure with python

Tags: python

I have a set of data for that I need identify patterns, so I tried to use `plt.contours` and `plt.contourf` for that task and it works well, now I can plot contours and show graphically the overdensity among the data. In this step, I tried to get the information of the surface contours (I mean, save the values that define the contour in a variable to use it later.) without success: Is there a way to do this?

Also, I have doubts of what does the values in the color bar means, I know that is the level of overdensity of the data, but if someone could tell me more details, would be great.

I attach the code that I'm using so far (I generate the data in this case), and a plot of the code.

```
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(20)

data = np.random.rand(400,2)

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))

# Set up a regular grid of points
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

#contours:
n_contours = 6
positions = np.vstack([xi.ravel(), yi.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xi.shape)

cfset = plt.contourf(xi, yi, f,n_contours, cmap='Greens')
cset = plt.contour(xi, yi, f,n_contours, colors='k')

#For the points data:
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, x.shape)

#plot:
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
plt.colorbar(cfset)
plt.show()
```

[image]

thanks!

EDIT:

I founded a way to do this, using the get_paths() feature, so basically, you need to choose the contour, and then the number of the segment that you need to get the values (x,y), for example:

```
#contour 3, section 0
p = cset.collections[3].get_paths()[0]
v = p.vertices
x0 = v[:,0]
y0 = v[:,1]
#contour 3, section 1
p = cset.collections[3].get_paths()[1]
v = p.vertices
x1 = v[:,0]
y1 = v[:,1]
#contour 3, section 2
p = cset.collections[3].get_paths()[2]
v = p.vertices
x2 = v[:,0]
y2 = v[:,1]

plt.plot(x0,y0,'-',x1,y1,'-',x2,y2,'-')
```

With this, you get:

[image]